# Efficient way for insertion of multiple rows at given indices & with repetitions

Tags: r, performance, dataframe

I have a data frame (DATA) with > 2 million rows (observations at different time points) and another data frame (INSERTION) which gives info about missing observations. The latter object contains 2 columns: 1st column with row indices after which empty (NA) rows should be inserted into DATA, and 2nd column with the number of empty rows that should be inserted at that position.

Below is a minimum working example:

```r
DATA <- data.frame(datetime=strptime(as.character(c(201301011700, 201301011701, 201301011703, 201301011704, 201301011705, 201301011708, 201301011710, 201301011711, 201301011715, 201301011716, 201301011718, 201301011719, 201301011721, 201301011722, 201301011723, 201301011724, 201301011725, 201301011726, 201301011727, 201301011729, 201301011730, 201301011731, 201301011732, 201301011733, 201301011734, 201301011735, 201301011736, 201301011737, 201301011738, 201301011739)), format="%Y%m%d%H%M"), var1=rnorm(30), var2=rnorm(30), var3=rnorm(30))
INSERTION <- data.frame(index=c(2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 19), repetition=c(1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1))
```

Now I'm looking for an efficient (and thus fast) way to insert the n empty rows at given row indices of the original file. How can I additionally complement the correct datetimes for these empty rows (add 1 minute for every new row; however, every weekend and bank holidays there are some regular gaps which are not contained in INSERTION!)?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is a factor on a large data frame, this approach avoids joins:

```
# Generate new data.frame containing missing datetimes  
tmp <- data.frame(datetime = DATA$datetime[with(INSERTION, rep(index, repetition))] + sequence(INSERTION$repetition)*60)

# Create variables filled with NA to match main data.frame
tmp[setdiff(names(DATA), names(tmp))] <- NA

# Bind and sort
new_df <- rbind(DATA, tmp)
new_df <- new_df[order(new_df$datetime),]

head(new_df, 15)

              datetime        var1        var2        var3
1  2013-01-01 17:00:00  0.98789253  0.68364933  0.70526985
2  2013-01-01 17:01:00 -0.68307496  0.02947599  0.90731512
31 2013-01-01 17:02:00          NA          NA          NA
3  2013-01-01 17:03:00 -0.60189915 -1.00153188  0.06165694
4  2013-01-01 17:04:00 -0.87329313 -1.81532302 -2.04930719
5  2013-01-01 17:05:00 -0.58713154 -0.42313098  0.37402224
32 2013-01-01 17:06:00          NA          NA          NA
33 2013-01-01 17:07:00          NA          NA          NA
6  2013-01-01 17:08:00  2.41350911 -0.13691754  1.57618578
34 2013-01-01 17:09:00          NA          NA          NA
7  2013-01-01 17:10:00 -0.38961552  0.83838954  1.18283382
8  2013-01-01 17:11:00  0.02290672 -2.10825367  0.87441448
35 2013-01-01 17:12:00          NA          NA          NA
36 2013-01-01 17:13:00          NA          NA          NA
37 2013-01-01 17:14:00          NA          NA          NA
```

Comment: You are incredible! - Thx 4 @Ronak Shah, too!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the pattern in `INSERTION` and matching it with `DATA` most probably you are trying to fill the missing minutes in `datetime` of `DATA`. You can create a dataframe with every minute sequence from `min` to `max` value of `datetime` from `DATA` and then `merge`

```
merge(data.frame(datetime = seq(min(DATA$datetime), max(DATA$datetime),
      by = "1 min")),DATA, all.x = TRUE)

#              datetime      var1     var2      var3
#1  2013-01-01 17:00:00 -1.063326  0.11925 -0.788622
#2  2013-01-01 17:01:00  1.263185  0.24369 -0.502199
#3  2013-01-01 17:02:00        NA       NA        NA
#4  2013-01-01 17:03:00 -0.349650  1.23248  1.496061
#5  2013-01-01 17:04:00 -0.865513 -0.51606 -1.137304
#6  2013-01-01 17:05:00 -0.236280 -0.99251 -0.179052
#7  2013-01-01 17:06:00        NA       NA        NA
#8  2013-01-01 17:07:00        NA       NA        NA
#9  2013-01-01 17:08:00 -0.197176  1.67570  1.902362
#10 2013-01-01 17:09:00        NA       NA        NA
#...
#...
```

Or using similar logic with `tidyr::complete`

```
tidyr::complete(DATA, datetime = seq(min(datetime), max(datetime), by = "1 min"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, there are some regular time gaps in the data which are NOT included in the INSERTION file. Sorry for that (just edited my question).

Comment: @Anti For 1st row in `INSERTION` you have 2 repetition so you mean you need to fill 2 `NA` rows? What would be the time in those rows since you have only 1 missing minute i.e `2013-01-01 17:02:00` ?